# PHP : cannot access array elements after foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am printing array elements

```
foreach($subcategories as $sucategory){
  print_r($sucategory);
  echo $subcategory[2];
  echo $subcategory[catid];
  echo $subcategory['catid'];
  echo $subcategory["catid"];
  echo $subcategory{"catid"};
  die();
}
```

The above code prints only the value of `print_r($subcategory)` but it didn't echo the value of catid in $subcategory..

```
Array
(
    [id] => 5
    [name] => 1
    [catid] => 10
    [status] => Y
)
```

and

```
echo $subcategories[0]['catid']; //prints 10 correctly
```

Comment: `TYPO` !!!!! Check your syntax. Tip:`b`

Comment: where is `subcategory` defined?

Comment: typo error.. it is sucategory not  subcategory, check carefully

Comment: in your loop you have `as sucategory` not as `subcategory`

Comment: @Bhaskar thanks bro

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions thanks bro

Comment: Please check, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/158591/how-to-avoid-typo-errors-etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error there. You use $sucategory and $subcategory, different names!

Copy/Paste this and it will work:

```
foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){
  print_r($subcategory);
  echo $subcategory["catid"];
  die();
}
```